# Python Boto3 not connecting to localstack

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, localstack

I am trying to simulate a dynamoDB on localstack, and I have my python running in a docker container and localstack running with environmental variables SERVICES=dynamodb,sqs

I also have another docker container running python and it is running all in the same network.

Here is a general overview:

```
Network: test-net-1
    -Container: Localstack-1
    -Container: Python-1
```

Inside my python script my code looks like this to create the dynamoDB:

```
self.dynamodb = boto3._get_default_session().resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url='Localstack-1')
```

and I get this error: ValueError: Invalid endpoint: Localstack-1

However, going into my docker container, if I do `ping Localstack-1`, it returns with a valid response:

```
64 bytes from Localstack-1.test-net-1 (172.22.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.239 ms
```

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried a full URL? `http://localstack-1`?

Comment: normally a url will have a protocol like http, https etc on the front as @kichik says try using the url and not just the hostname

Comment: Still same error: Invalid endpoint: http://Localstack-1

Comment: Oh, I just realized how this looks when I posted the comment. Yes, I did add the http:// afterwards, with the same error. I have also added the port 4566 as well, with the same error.

Comment: Please make sure you correctly updated it. For me, `dynamodb = boto3._get_default_session().resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://Localstack-1:4566')` works fine. If you are interested, you can find the criteria of the endpoint url in the botocore source here: https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/0417256c7f80e3a6d6ca07a65bfa5ddf4069252c/botocore/utils.py#L1230 
Also, I would not access the default session like this. Per default, boto3.resource should also proxy to the default session, without having to access a private field.